# Convert unix timestamp to javascript date Object

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

Am working with json api that represents dates like this

```
"date" : "/Date(1356081900000)/"
```

I want to turn this into regular javascript Date.

The only way I can think of solving this problem is to do a replace on everything leaving the timestamp which I can then "convert".

This works but it just looks wrong.

My question. Can I do this in better way?

**UPDATE**

```
 unix_timestamp = jsonDate.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', '');

 newDate = new Date(+unix_timestamp + 1000*3600);
```

Comment: Did you see this other post?  [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date).

Accepted solution was:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:-

```
 var d = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
```

or

```
 var d = new Date([UNIX Timestamp] * 1000);
```

Comment: this works for me, ten a simple `return t.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + t.toLocaleTimeString();`  in my function

Answer (score 0):

The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor accepts a Unix timestamp.

```
function cleanDate(d) {
    return new Date(+d.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//, '$1'));
}

cleanDate("/Date(1356081900000)/"); // => Fri Dec 21 2012 04:25:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```