# Date value is displaying in wrong format when using jquery And Json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datetime

I'm  returning created date value from Sql server and placing it in a div using jquery.But  i'm getting value as "/Date(1385716781000)/" but i need it as dd/mm/yy format.

I'm getting the value as "2013-11-29 14:03:33.160" in my model while returning but in view while debugging i found it in above format.

```
$.getJSON( '@Url.Action("GetTicketdetails")',  { TicketID: ticketid }, function (items) {
  debugger;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var s = s + '<li >' + '<div class="divInsidediv" >' + items[i].CreatedDate + '</div>';
  }
  $('#divA').html(s);
});
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: I did use items[i].CreatedDate.toString("dd/mm/yy") but it caught an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the date in json forma like this

Use this function to convert Json Date date

```
function renderDate(value) {
  if (value == '' || value == undefined) {
    return '';
  }
  else {
    getDate = new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
  }
  //You can - or / as what ever you want
  return (
    getDate.getDate()  + "/" + (getDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + getDate.getFullYear()
  );
}
```

You function will be converted like this

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetTicketdetails")', { TicketID: ticketid }, function (items){
  debugger;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var s = s + '<li>' + '<div class="divInsidediv" >' +
      renderDate(items[i].CreatedDate) + '</div>';
  }
  $('#divA').html(s);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting `UNIX timestamp` you can use [date.format()](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/) like,

```
new Date(items[i].CreatedDate  * 1000).format('d/m/y');
```

Try this in you code,

```
var  s ='';// initialize s here, once
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   d=new Date(items[i].CreatedDate  * 1000).format('d/m/y');
   s += '<li><div class="divInsidediv">' + d +  '</li></div>';  
}
```

**Updated** or try simply,

```
var  s ='';// initialize s here, once
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   d=Date(items[i].CreatedDate); // let you get 1385716781000 in items[i].CreatedDate
   nd=(d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getDay()+'/'+d.getFullYear();// new date
   s += '<li><div class="divInsidediv">' + nd +  '</li></div>';  
}
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) and [Convert unix timestamp to javascript date Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994083/convert-unix-timestamp-to-javascript-date-object)

Comment: Did not work :( Error shown as object[object Date] has no method format. Replaced format with getDate but getting output as NaN

Comment: Have you added code from http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/ for `format()`

Comment: I added the code for format and now m getting output as "Nan/Nan/Nan"

Comment: The second link helped me understand more. Thanks !! :)